# Spring Security - always redirect to failure-url

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to use Spring Security in my application, but after every successful registration, when it comes to sign in I meet a problem. Spring redirects me to failureUrl. I feel tired of looking for my mistake. Could you show me the proper way? I'd really appreciate. There's code with security config:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private RegisterService registerService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/registration",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/img/**",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(registerService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

}
```

And service responible for signing up and in

```
@Service
public class RegisterService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User save(UserDto userDto){
        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin(userDto.getLogin());
        user.setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(userDto.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
        user.setRole("ROLE_USER");
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public User findByEmail(String email){
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public User findByLogin(String login){
        return userRepository.findByLogin(login);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByLogin(login);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getLogin(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `defaultSuccessUrl` in your configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
                "/registration",
                "/js/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/img/**",
                "/webjars/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
}
```

I also think calling `permitAll()` for the `formLogin` is redundant as this is the default but this shouldn't be a problem.